# How to Query the entity type from dbpedia

Tags: python, python-3.x, sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to query just the entity type from dbpedia using SPARQL but I am not getting any output. I am trying to query dbpedia in the following manner.

```
sparql.setQuery("""
    PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
    select str(?text) as ?text where
    {
    db:Flipkart dct:description ?text 
    FILTER (lang(?text) = 'en')
    }
""")
```

I want the output as "Company" or "Indian Company" or anything similar. Can anyone please help?

Comment: I don't get query question. Your query is trying to get the description of a resource - so how should this return the type? And then, do you think `dct:description` exists for the entity in DBpedia? Did you open the page for the entity in your browser? The only properties close to descriptions are `dbo:abstract` and `rdfs:comment` - so from where do you have the property?

Comment: by the way, you're doing some university homework here for sure and are not the first asking here for the query returning of all Indian companies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57865489/sparql-query-to-retrieve-all-indian-brand-names-from-dbpedia apparently, that's usually not how homework assignment works, other people doing your tasks, but ok ...

Comment: Credits to me please when you submit the homework: `prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> select distinct ?company where { { ?company a dbo:Company; dbo:location|dbo:locationCountry|dbo:country dbr:India } union { ?company a dbo:Company; dct:subject/skos:broader* <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Companies_of_India> } } order by ?company`

Comment: I am aware that dct:description is not there on the dbpedia page for Flipkart. I want to know the generic key that would work for all kinds of entities. For all dbpedia pages it says entity of type:<something>. I want that <something> for all entities

Comment: *"I am aware that dct:description is not there on the dbpedia page for Flipkart."* - and that do you use it in your query and then wonder why the result is empty? I don't get it

Comment: regarding getting the type: using `rdf:type` property with a variable in object position is no option for you? Like you did for `dct:description`?

Comment: `PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
    select ?type (str(?text) as ?text) where
    {
    db:Flipkart rdf:type ?type; dbo:abstract ?text 
    FILTER (lang(?text) = 'en')
    }`

Comment: The query in the question is an example of what I am trying to do. I want to know if a generic key exists that works for all dbpedia entities.

Comment: what is a "generic key"? That term doesn't exist in RDF or SPARQL ... did you try my last query? It returns all types as well as the English description. IS that not what you want? And it works for all entities, just change the subject to whatever. If you even don't want to set a subject, then just replace it by a variable - that's the whole concept of SPARQL. `select ?s ?type where {?s rdf:type ?type}` returns entity + type(s) - and yes, one row for each type, another basic concept of SPARQL

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology>
SELECT DISTINCT ?obj WHERE{
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jim_Halpert>  rdf:type ?obj
FILTER strstarts(str(?obj), str(dbo:))}
```

In this particular case I'm looking for all the types of an entity, using rdf:type as a relation and the actual type as an object. As you can see, types in dbpedia are distinguished by the prefix str(dbo:).

Jim_Halpert_type:

[image]